# FBDataAdapter hangs on fill using StoredProc

Tags: .net, firebird, interbase

I am having a weird problem. I am using Firebird for .Net and using Interbase database. When I try to fill dataset using a SQL query it works fine, but when I try to execute a storedProc it hangs on fill method.

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 FbDataAdapter ada = new FbDataAdapter("spsGetLastOpened",        System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydb"].ConnectionString);
 ada.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 ada.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@USER_KEY",2);
 ada.Fill(dt);
```

I googled the problem people suggested that it happens if there already an open connection with the database, So I created a stand-alone utility which does not opens connection (Dataadapter manages connection on its own).

Please advice what am I doing wrong here.

Kind Regards,
Ali

Comment: Just what are you using? Firebird or Interbase, they are two different databases that have diverged in the past 11 years.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using firebird for .Net but I want to remeber one thing. You can execute stored procedure as regular sql statement

-execute procedure SomeProc(?,...)

or for selectable procs

-select * from SomeProc(?,....)

Comment: CommandType.StoredProcedure;  << think this is must be changed

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who lands here from google..
I don't know what the reason is but, when I executed as transaction it worked. I only ran the select query, I cant understand why it worked?